# Android, File.length() return 0 (sometimes), for existing (allways) file

Tags: android, file, camera, is-empty

Sorry, for my English, and for the fact that it was difficult for me to come up with a comprehensive title for this issue.

I get a photo from the camera. How can you overcome the strange behavior on the android 6.0 version of the following code. When running on the emulator API23 and on a device with version 4.0.3 this never happens!

```
ContentValues valuesHeaders = new ContentValues();
File photoFile = new File(fileName);    

//
//big problem - 8 times from 10 length value is 0 
valuesHeaders.put("columnname", photoFile.length());
....
//
//big problem - 8 times from 10 blob is empty
RandomAccessFile randomAccessFile = new RandomAccessFile(photoFile, "r");
byte blob[] = new byte[(int) photoFile.length()];
randomAccessFile.readFully(blob);
```

But at the same time, a few lines of code below (but in the beginning it was higher, but I changed places to avoid any influence), in the same function, this file is always available
for extracting the thumbnail. ALWAYS and both ways, on ALL device (4.0.3 and 6.0) and emulator API23.

```
ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(fileName);
if (exif.hasThumbnail()) {
   byte[] thumbnail = exif.getThumbnail();
}else{
     ...
     BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fileName, options);
     ...
}
```

Why length() return 0?

Comment: Off the top of my head, you are using the wrong file path, hence the length is showing up as zero.

Comment: wrong for FILE.length() , but perfect for ExifInterface(fileName) - that is the question. I think either about premature / parallel execution (the file is not ready for the request from "IO.File API"), or something related to PATH vs URI.